# Fragment with ListView is always empty Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview

I want to create a search with a simply database query. So what I got is quite simple: I have a toolbar with a `search-item` that has an `OnQueryTextListener` implemented.

When the user submits the search I want to navigate to my `SearchResultFragment` and pass the query. There I simply want a `ListView` with all the results. Anyway, the `SearchResultFragment` opens, but there are not entries in my List whatsoever.

Also, there is no exception thrown or anything, so I'm not quite sure why it doesn't work. I already tried making the search with an Activity, but I couldn't get it to work out and I also thought that it was quite complicated/overkill for such a simple use case.

**My Fragment code:**

```
public class SearchResultFragment extends Fragment {
    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result, container, false);
        SearchListAdapter searchListAdapter = new SearchListAdapter(getActivity());
        LiveData<List<Plant>> plantLiveDataList;
        
        //Find the query name
        String query = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("query") : "";

        PlantDao plantDao = PlantDatabase.getAppDatabase(getContext()).plantDao();
        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            plantLiveDataList = plantDao.findAll();
        } else {
            plantLiveDataList = plantDao.searchForName("%"+query+"%");
        }
        plantLiveDataList.observe(this, searchListAdapter::addPlant);
        
        //Add at least 1 object to be sure!
        Plant plant = new Plant();
        plant.setPlantName("blub");
        searchListAdapter.addPlant(plant);
        
        ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchResultListView);
        listView.setAdapter(searchListAdapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**The PlantDao class for DB-Access**

```
@Dao
public interface PlantDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM plant")
    LiveData<List<Plant>> findAll();

    @Query("Select * From plant where plantName LIKE :name")
    LiveData<List<Plant>> searchForName(String name);
}
```

**My Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".search.SearchResultFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/searchResultListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**My Listitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And my Custom Adapter**

```
public class SearchListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Plant> plantList = new ArrayList<Plant>();
    private Activity context;

    public SearchListAdapter(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addPlant(List<Plant> plants) {
        for (Plant plant : plants) {
            this.plantList.add(plant);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addPlant(final Plant plant) {
        this.plantList.add(plant);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return plantList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Plant getItem(int position) {
        return this.plantList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return this.plantList.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlistitem, null, true);

        TextView itemTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);

        itemTitle.setText(this.getItem(position).getPlantName());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**Last but not least - My Call from Main Activity -> this actually works so far**

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("query", query);
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_to_searchresult, args);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

==========================
Update:

When I insert Logging the plant names:

```
public void addPlant(List<Plant> plants) {
    for (Plant plant : plants) {
        this.plantList.add(plant);
        Log.println(Log.INFO,"SearchResult", "Added Plant To List with Name: " + plant.getPlantName());
        Log.println(Log.INFO, "SearchResult", "PlantList now Containing " + this.plantList.size() + " elments.");
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addPlant(final Plant plant) {
    this.plantList.add(plant);
    Log.println(Log.INFO, "SearchResult", "Added Plant To List with Name: " + plant.getPlantName());
    Log.println(Log.INFO, "SearchResult", "PlantList now Containing " + this.plantList.size() + " elments.");
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I get the following output on my manually added plant:

> I/SearchResult: Added Plant To List with Name: blub
>
> I/SearchResult: PlantList now Containing 1 elments.

Yet no List Elements shown.

Comment: Change `Listitem.xml` `LinearLayout` height to `wrap_content`. Can you check if `plantList` has items in it by logging? Also, where is this layout `R.layout.searchlistitem`? It should be the name of your list item(`ListItem.xml`?) layout file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the `wrap_content` - I changed it :) I added some logging + output on the very bottom. Even if my DB doesn not give any results when I enter a name that is not in it, I still have the problem that I manually add a plant and that one is in the list, so every query should give at least one item in the `ListView`.

Comment: Log the same thing in the adapter's `getCount`. Also, check the name of the layout file.

Comment: Change your getView code in adapter like this and check: View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlistitem, parent, false); // pass parent and false instead of null and true.

Comment: @Ranjan Logged getCount, it also says the same number as the other log.

Comment: @Bob Changed the code, sadly did not change the outcome :(

Comment: You need to `return view;` from `onCreateView()`, not `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)`.

Comment: @Mike M. That did the trick, thanks!!